# how to create sql table with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database

I am wanting to create a sqlDB on my server, I am very new to db development and have only done the odd bit of coding here an there several years ago. I am trying to build a db that has four tables that reference each other..

This is what each of the tables are created for to give you a better idea as to what I am trying to achieve.

**Group**
this table will store hubs which users create for other users to follow.

**User**
stores users details which are used when creating groups and joining groups

//Not sure if this next one is a good idea but hopefully someone can let me know what they thing about it
**userGroups**
this table stores all or the groups and user connections. When a user joins a group their id is stored with the group id.

**Countries**
countries are used to help restrict the number of results that can be returned

heres the code I have created that I would like to run on my DB.. I am not sure if I have made the foreign keys correctly, any advice on that would be appreciated also.

```
CREATE DATABASE tempDB
USE tempDB

CREATE TABLE Group (groupID UInt32 PRIMARY KEY, userID UInt32 references User(SID), country VARCHAR(20) references Country(SID));

CREATE TABLE User (userID UInt32 PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(20), country VARCHAR(20) references Country(SID));

CREATE TABLE userGroups (userID references User(SID), groupID UInt32 references Group(SID));

CREATE TABLE countries (countryName VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY);
```

so three questions:

1. Is the table UserGroups worth while?
2. Have I created the foreign Keys correctly?
3. Will this code create a DB with the 4 tables in them...

Comment: Why is countryName a primary key? From what I know, I think primary keys are supposed to be numbers.

Comment: @redelman431 primary keys can be any unique identifier.  Numbers, strings, anything... Even combinations of multiple columns as t

Comment: @redelman431 primary keys can be any type as long as they are unique values.  Even composite of multiple columns as long as the combination is unique.

Comment: Cool! lets hope there are no countries with the same name out there LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your users can be in many groups and many users can be in a group drop the column and foreign key reference to the userid field in the group table.  The usergroups table handles this many-to-many mapping.

Your current setup would only make sense if say each group had also a single 'owner' user...

Also, what DB engine are you using?  Innodb or myisam... If myisam foreign keys are jest like any other index without any ability to enforce constraints, therefore not really useful to try and declare.

Comment: okay regarding your second sentence, yes that userid FK in the group table is for the creator of the group... So I am guessing that part of it is alright then. Regarding your last sentence.. I have no idea what DB engine I am using, how can I find out? lastly.. dose this code look like it would work if i used it in its current stat without taking into account what db engine I am using? Finally thank you very much for helping me out ;)

Answer (score 1):

- Before creating any table which has a foreign key that table should be created.
- Country(SID)- there is no table Country and field SID
- Countries table should have a id field as primary key.
- To use foreign keys you should specify the engine =INNODB
- To check if tables have been created with Forign key

  ```
  mysql> Show tables // Shows all created table
  mysql> desc tableName  // to see the structure of the created table
  ```

Comment: Great thanks a bunch for the informaiton I'm going to attempt this shortly.. just trying to find out where I can specify the engine to be INNODB.

Comment: `create table tableName( fd int, fd1 varchar(20) )engine=innodb;`

Comment: oh right, so you actually declare what engine you would like your table to use?